# Simple question about the definition of an internal groupoid.

Tags: category-theory

This probably will sound like a stupid question. But it is nevertheless a question of mine, so I will ask.

Under which assumptions is the pullback of two arrows $s,t:A_1\to A_0$ the cartesian product $A_1\times A_1$ ? 
To be more specific, I am looking at the definition of an internal groupoid in the page 
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category.
They use morphisms (the diagonal) to the cartesian product $C_1\times C_1$ to define the internal groupoid. Shouldn't the squares that are required to be commutative involve the pullback $C_1\times_{C_0} C_1$? There is most likely something very simple that I don't get here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What they're more or less taking for granted is that we have the identities $si = t$ and $ti = s$. These conditions aren't mentioned, and I think they should.

For, using those, we can show that:

$${\rm id} \times i: C_1 \times C_1 \to C_1 \times C_1$$

(which gives rise to $p_1({\rm id}\times i): C_1 \times C_1 \to C_1$ and $p_2({\rm id}\times i): C_1 \times C_1 \to C_1$) satisfies:

$$tp_1({\rm id}\times i) = t = si = sp_2({\rm id}\times i)$$

so that there is a morphism $\widetilde{{\rm id}\times i}: C_1 \times C_1 \to C_1 \times_{C_0} C_1$ which allows for the formation of $c (\widetilde{{\rm id}\times i}): C_1 \times C_1 \to C_1$.

With this hurdle taken, we can verify that the two diagrams express that $i$ takes a generalized element of $C_1$ to its two-sided inverse under $c$.

But I really think that the conditions $si =t$ and $ti=s$ are missing on the nCatLab page. (We haven't used $ti =s$ yet, but I suspect that it comes into play when we want to prove that $ii = {\rm id}$.)

Comment: Yes the nlab page should be corrected.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. What I don't understand is why they use the cartesian product. I mean, why do they not use the composition $c\circ \binom{1_{C_1}}{i}$ instead of $\left(c\circ(1\circ i)\right)\circ \text{diag}$ on defining the first square that is required to be commutative? (Which is what other authors do)

Comment: @user112358 I don't know. Perhaps it has something to do with the other omission as well (for making it a mapping to the pullback makes one acknowledge that it actually works, which requires the identities).